# Literature on non-equilibrium statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, non-equilibrium

I am a graduate student, currently planning on self-studying non-equilibrium statistical mechanics. I have tried searching for literature myself, but no book/online course that I have found seems comprehensive yet friendly enough, so I would like to get recommendations for some good literature.

The subjects that I am interested to get a deep understanding about, include:

1. Stochastic processes, Markovian and Gaussian processes, harmonic analysis, correlation
   functions, Wiener-Khintchine theorem.
2. Brownian motion, random walk, diffusion equation, Einstein relations.
3. Langevin equation, Fokker-Planck equation, Multiplicative random cascade
4. Stochastic path integrals.
5. Fluctuation dissipation theorem.
6. Boltzmann equation, collision integral, τ-approximation, Boltzmann entropy, and H-theorem.
7. Linear response theory, Kramers-Kronig relations, dielectric relaxation.
8. Jarzynski equality and its extensions.
9. Elementary transport theory and macroscopic continuum theory.
10. Green-Kubo formula.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226929/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256895/2451